# Printing a list of all items with an odd index in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

This code is printing the even indexes:

```
(define (odd list)
  (if (or (null? list) (null? (cdr list)))
      list
      (cons (car list) (odd (cddr list)))))
```

When the file runs my input is:
`odd '(0 2 3 7 5)` and it should return `(2 7)`, but instead it returns `(0 3 5)`.

I think one of my `null?`s are wrongly placed, but I am not sure where!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here. To begin, do not use `list` as a parameter in a procedure definition; this redefines the built-in `list` procedure within `odd`, making it unavailable (not that you need it here).

When the `car` or the `cdr` of the input list is `null?`, OP code returns the input list; this is not correct. If the `cdr` of the input list is empty, then the input is a list of one element which has an even index. Instead, return `'()` in this case.

Finally, consider:

```
(cons (car list) (odd (cddr list)))
```

This `cons`es the first element of the input list onto the resulting list of odd-indexed elements; but, the first element of the input list *always* has an even index! This is because the first element of the initial input list has index 0, and every input list in a recursive call also begins with an even-indexed element thanks to the reduction `(cddr list)`. Instead, code needs to `cons` the *second* element of the input list (the `cadr`) onto the resulting list of odd-indexed elements.

Here is a corrected version:

```
(define (odd xs)
  (if (or (null? xs) (null? (cdr xs)))
      '()
      (cons (cadr xs) (odd (cddr xs)))))
```

Sample REPL interaction:

```
> (odd '())
()
> (odd '(0))
()
> (odd '(0 2))
(2)
> (odd '(0 2 3 7 5))
(2 7)
```